# Inserting space or hyphen after 3 and 6 digits, and having prefix +91

Tags: javascript, html

Iwant to have +91 pefix in the input text which can be unchanged, and after entering the data getting space or hyphen after 3rd and 6th digits ... Is it possible? this is my code, plz help!! thank you in advance

```
   function ValidateMobNumber(txtMobId) {
      var fld = document.getElementById(txtMobId);

      if (fld.value == "") {
      alert("You didn't enter a phone number.");
      fld.value = "";
      fld.focus();
      return false;
     }
      else if (isNaN(fld.value)) {
      alert("The phone number contains illegal characters.");
      fld.value = "";
      fld.focus();
      return false;
     }
     else if (!(fld.value.length == 10)) {
      alert("The phone number is the wrong length. \nPlease enter 10 digit mobile no.");
      fld.value = "";
      fld.focus();
      return false;
     }

    }

    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <input type="text" id="txtMB" />
    <!--Or Call on Button-->

    <input type="submit" id="btnVal" value="Save" onclick="return ValidateMobNumber('txtMB')" />
```

Answer (score 0):

The regex you are looking for, is:

```
^\+91 ?\d{3}([ -]{1})?\d{3}([ -]{1})?\d{3}$
/* valid are:
    +91 123 456-789
    +91123456789
    +91 123-456-789
    etc.

    the regex means: +91, optional space, 3 numbers, optional one space or hyphen, the same once again and three numbers at the end.
*/
```

When you want to test regexp in JavaScript, you need to use method `.test`, see my code below.

```
<form onsubmit="return ValidateMobNumber('txtMB');">
    <input type="text" id="txtMB">
    <input type="submit" id="btnVal" value="Save">
<form>

<script>
    function ValidateMobNumber(txtMobId) {
        var fld = document.getElementById(txtMobId);
        var patt = /\+91 ?\d{3}([ -]{1})?\d{3}([ -]{1})?\d{3}$/;
        var res = patt.test(fld.value);

        alert(res); // just for testing to show you if phone number is valid or not, remove that
        return res;
    }
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yv4dyoLg/

See that you don't need your 3 conditions in the validate funtion, the code above is complete and error message could be 'You inserted invalid phone number'.

Than I moved return value into `onsubmit` action for formular, because you can send it using Enter. When you press enter button, `onclick` isn't activate on `submit input`.